# DB2 foreign key with on delete set null not working for two columns referencing same column of parent table

Tags: database, db2, foreign-keys

I have following ddl

```
CREATE TABLE ABC (
COL1 INTEGER NOT NULL,
COL2 VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
COL3 VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
COL4 INTEGER NOT NULL

);

ALTER TABLE ABC
ADD CONSTRAINT ABC_PK PRIMARY KEY 
    (COL1,
     COL4);

CREATE TABLE XYZ (
COL1 INTEGER NOT NULL,
COL2 INTEGER,
COL3 INTEGER,
COL4 INTEGER

);      


ALTER TABLE XYZ
ADD CONSTRAINT COL_2_FK FOREIGN KEY
    (COL2,
     COL4)
REFERENCES ABC
    (COL1,
     COL4)
ON DELETE SET NULL
ON UPDATE NO ACTION 
ENFORCED 
ENABLE QUERY OPTIMIZATION; 

ALTER TABLE XYZ
ADD CONSTRAINT COL_3_FK FOREIGN KEY
    (COL3,
     COL4)
REFERENCES ABC
    (COL1,
     COL4)
ON DELETE SET NULL
ON UPDATE NO ACTION 
ENFORCED 
ENABLE QUERY OPTIMIZATION;
```

the last Alter table fails with following error:

```
FOREIGN KEY "COL_3_FK" is not valid because it would cause a descendent    table "DB2ADMIN.X" to be delete-connected to its ancestor table "DB2ADMIN.A" through multiple relationships with conflicting delete rules. The conflict is between the delete rules of constraints "DB2ADMIN.XYZ.CO" and "DB2ADMIN.XYZ.COL_3_FK" on the descendent table. Reason code = "3".. SQLCODE=-20255, SQLSTATE=42915, DRIVER=3.68.61
```

I found on IBM DB2 documentation :
When a table is delete-connected to another table through multiple relationships where such relationships have overlapping foreign keys, these relationships must have the same delete rule and none of these can be SET NULL.

But I do not understand the rationale behind it?
And how do I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the rationale is pretty simple: the `SET NULL` delete rule of `COL_2_FK` causes the affected row to violate `COL_3_FK` (and vice versa) -- `COL4` is set to null, while it must reference a valid value in `ABC.COL4`. As to how you can overcome the problem -- rethink your constraints (or the model).

Comment: I wouldn't call that "work". Oracle may let you create those constraints, but then your data violate those same constraints.